# How will raspberry PI handle having Daylight savings time locked on

Tags: real-time, timekeeping, systemd-timesyncd

Congress has passed a bill to lock daylight savings time on. How will the PI handle this.

What I mean by this is how will the PI know to use the "permanent" daylight savings time?

Answer (score 1):

It will have no effect on the Pi since it does not have a RTC (Real Time Clock). However users are expected to have it always connected to WiFi or Ethernet and keep time by checking the network as the operating system maintains the time, not the Pi. In the end it is all controlled with software which can be updated. External hardware can be added if so desired such as a RTC chip.

Comment: `It will have no effect on the Pi ...`. Yes, it will have an effect. Please review your answer after you've read up on how RPi syncs its time over the network.

Answer (score 0):

Your RPi and the vast majority of all other Linux systems will "handle" this change in exactly the same way it is handled now: ***You will need to do nothing.*** You don't do anything now to change your system time when DST begins or ends, and you won't need to do anything after the change is incorporated. The [`tzdata` file](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/tzdata) that defines DST start and end dates is updated periodically through the routine `apt` update & upgrade processes. This latest change to DST will be transparent to users and administrators.

As far as our systems are concerned, the new "permanent" DST for the USA is far easier than changing time periodically to reflect politically-mandated schedules for DST. The only thing you need to do is to make sure that the entry in `/etc/localtime` reflects the timezone you wish to track on your system. You can change that via `raspi-config` if you wish.

The only exceptions to this - the only users who may need to take action are those that are not using `systemd-timesyncd`, or have replaced their system's network time source with perhaps a GPS or other external timekeeping system.

For those who are curious about *how* this is done, there is a reasonably good [explanation of the underlying configuration](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/update-linux-and-freebsd-systems-for-new-daylight-saving-time-settings/) that makes this automation possible. It was written about 15 years ago (the last time our *political leadership* decided to change DST), but nothing much has changed since then.